# Install ARKit enable project on non supported devices

Tags: swift, xcode, arkit

I am experimenting the ARKit and I want to develop an application which is hybrid of ARKit and some other functionality. Now I can find out programmatically that a particular device supports the ARKit or not as follows;

```
if (!ARConfiguration.isSupported) {
  print("this device is not supported for Measure functionality")
} else {
  print("This device support ARKit.")
}
```

depending on the above flag I will use the ARKit or normal functionality. But the problem is if I go to install my application on any iPad which don't have A9 chip on, Xcode straight away refuses to install the application on device with the following message:

```
“App” requires the “arkit” capability which is not supported by iPad
```

Does anyone know any decent method that I can still install this app on my iPad and then then do the functionality on the basis of `isSupported` flag from inside the app?

Comment: Remove arkit from the required device capabilities if you want your app to be able to be installed on devices that don't have arkit

Comment: Also note you should check `isSupported` on the configuration class you intend to use, not the abstract base class... e.g. `ARWorldTrackingConfiguration.isSupported`.